# SpringFox swagger-ui integration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger-ui, springfox

My output generated in the swagger-ui is:

```
DocumentChangeSet {
deletes (Collection«DocumentKey», optional),
updates (Collection«AbstractDocument», optional)
}
Collection«DocumentKey» {}
Collection«AbstractDocument» {}
```

Is there any way to make it go into more detail for the

`deletes (Collection«DocumentKey», optional),`
and
`updates (Collection«AbstractDocument», optional)`
to give a full break down of each of these parts?

My docket looks as follows:

```
    @Bean
public Docket api(){

    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .genericModelSubstitutes(DeferredResult.class)
            .alternateTypeRules(
                    newRule(typeResolver.resolve(DeferredResult.class,
                            typeResolver.resolve(DeferredResult.class,DocumentChangeSet.class)),
                            DocumentChangeSet.class)
            )
            .pathMapping("/")
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());
}
```

To add more detail both documentKey and abstractDocument are annotated.

Below is the DocumentChangeSet class without any annotations.

```
    public DocumentChangeSet(Collection<? extends AbstractDocument> updates, Collection<DocumentKey> deletes) {
    this.updates = ImmutableSet.copyOf(updates);
    this.deletes = ImmutableSet.copyOf(deletes);
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return Objects.toStringHelper(this)
            .add("updates", updates.size())
            .add("deletes", deletes.size())
            .toString();
}
public Collection<AbstractDocument> getUpdates() {
    return updates;
}

public Collection<DocumentKey> getDeletes() {
    return deletes;
}
```

Comment: how have you annotated the DocumentChangeSet class?

Comment: @Sampada no im unsure what to annotate it

Comment: check this [link](http://heidloff.net/article/usage-of-swagger-2-0-in-spring-boot-applications-to-document-apis/)

Comment: @Sampada is the only way to do it with the Api annotations?

Answer (score 1):

The way swagger works is, it scans your REST API code for annotations (these could be specific [Swagger annotations](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X) or [JAX-RS annotations](http://www.techferry.com/articles/RESTful-web-services-JAX-RS-annotations.html), or even [Jackson annotations](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonAnnotations)) and generates a JSON out of it.

This `swagger.json` is then fed to Swagger UI and the beautiful UI page is generated for you.

Long answer short, it is neccesary to use annotations.

Comment: ok this makes sense as it was picking up the jackson annotations for the other classes, looks like im messing one to bridge the gap between DocumentChangeSet and documentKey

Comment: I'm still unable to bridge the gap between DocumentChangeSet and the annotated key, any advice?